# JQuery + Watir - event handlers not working

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, watir

I have a droplist on a webpage that I am trying to test with Watir.  While watir successfully selects the item in the droplist, the jQuery change event isn't fired.

Is there any way to get Watir (using IE) to fire the jQuery change event?

Answer (score 1):

I already had jquery in the page, so I was able to solve this by having Watir execute some javascript to fire the change event (after I had changed the selection in the droplist)

```
 @browser = Watir::Browser.new
 @browser.goto("http://someurl")
 @browser.select_list(:id, element_id).select(item_to_select)
 @browser.ie.Document.parentWindow.execScript('$("##{element_id}").change();')
```

Where:

- element_id is the id of the droplist in question
- item_to_select is the item to select in the droplist

Comment: You should accept your answer so that this no longer shows up on the list of questions without answers

Answer (score 0):

You can try the .fire_event method.  For example:

```
browser.link(:id, "id").fire_event("onmouseover")
```

http://wtr.rubyforge.org/rdoc/1.6.5/classes/Watir/Element.html#M000557.

Comment: I've tried fireEvent('onChange') and fireEvent('onchange') neither of which does anything.  fireEvent('change') throws an exception: Invalid argument

Comment: I also tried fire_event() instead of fireEvent() with identical results

Comment: Hmm...what about .send_keys?  EG: .send_keys("{ENTER}") - http://wtr.rubyforge.org/rdoc/1.6.5/classes/Watir/IE.html#M000497